# Save text in a list or other

Tags: prolog

I have this code:

```
open('file.txt', append, Stream),          
write(Stream, (clause(t1))),  
close(Stream)
```

I repeat it several times in my program, then I open and close the file several times. Can I open the file only once saving the content in a list with append and finally I save this list in a file?

Comment: where does `clause(t1)` etc. come from? Can't you just make one list with append and save *it* to the file? Or do you get this info somehow *dynamically*, from external source? You still can collect it through `asserta` and `retract`.

Comment: Sorry, this `clause(t1)` is derived from some previous evaluations that I did not write. I obtain in my file this : `clause(t1),clause(t2),clause(t3)` after several cycles. How can I do to obtain this without opening the file several times but only once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a symbolic alias for Stream, then [open](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=open/4) the file with a chosen alias, run your program, issuing writes passing the *alias* as Stream, then close the file when done.

Here a dummy example:

```
save :-
    open('myfile.txt', write, _, [alias(clauses)]),
    forall(between(1,100,N),
           format(clauses, 'clause(~d).~n', N)),
    close(clauses).
```

then 'myfile.txt' will contains

```
clause(1).
clause(2).
clause(3).
...
clause(99).
clause(100).
```

the point to note is the alias used to reference the stream...

Comment: Can I call alias by other rules? For example `save1` `save2` `save3`. Or should I open the file for each rule?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question... but yes, you can use the same alias for different rules. An alias it's a kind of global variable...

Comment: If i have `save:-open('myfile.txt', write, _, [alias(clauses)]),
    forall(between(1,100,N),
           format(clauses, 'clause(~d).~n', N)),
    close(clauses).` and then `save2:-open('myfile.txt', write, _, [alias(clauses)]),
    forall(between(101,200,N),
           format(clauses, 'clause(~d).~n', N)),
    close(clauses).`, i have the same problem because in two rules i open two times the file.

Comment: Don't open the file two times. Open once at program start and use the same alias everywhere

Comment: And if the format of alias is different and not always  `clause(~d) `, how can I do?

Comment: That has nothing to do with `alias`. Of course, you must use the appropriate `format` specifier for each clause you must save. Mine was only a silly example...